# Can't hide createBottomTabNavigator in React Navigation v2

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

Looking to hide createBottomTabNavigator on a specific screen in my application. (react navigation v2)

I’m navigating to the route I want hidden by reseting the stack:

```
const test = StackActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'TEST_SCREEN' })],
});

this.props.navigation.dispatch(test);
```

then in my TestScreen component I’ve tried the following:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
let tabBarVisible = true;
console.log(navigation.state);
if (navigation.state.routeName === 'TEST_SCREEN') {
  tabBarVisible = false;
}

return {
  tabBarVisible
 };
}

// static navigationOptions = {
 // tabBarVisible: false
// }
```

console.log output:

```
Object {params: undefined, routeName: "TEST_SCREEN", key: "id-1524534842146-12"}
key: "id-1524534842146-12"
params:undefined
routeName: "TEST_SCREEN"
__proto__: Object
```

Only information I can seem to find is `https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1949`and it’s outdated (react-navigation v1)

Thoughts?